# How do I add a related id to RethinkDB table?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have been exploring RethinkDB. I have two tables: `User`, `Post`. When loaded, RethinkDB generates an `id` for each table, but I want to store the related `User.id` as `Post.user_id` for each post in the `Post` table.

How do I create the relevant field in the `Post` table documents to allow `eq_join`s to be a useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field using `update`. If you know the `user_id` for a particular post, you can write

```
r.table('posts').get(POST_ID).update({user_id: USER_ID})
```